# SSMS: split result panel from SQL panel

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I use 2 monitors. I already maximize SSMS's windows. I'd like to split its result panel from its SQL panel, so that I have a full monitor for query and a full monitor for the result.

Is it possible?

Comment: Only if you can make the two monitors top and bottom instead of left and right.

Comment: you can put them top and bottom logically in windows setting while keeping them next to each other phisically.

Comment: Do you mean manually place SSMS in both monitors and place the separator between them?